# changing list view data when the list is moving

Tags: android, listview

I have a `listview` with some data and 2 `buttons` when the button is pressed the data in the `listview` changes. To obtain this when the `button` is clicked i change the value in the `arraylist` and call `notifyDatasetChanged`. All these works fine. But when i move the list with one finger and click the button the app crashes with error `The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification` . The data is changed from the UI thread itself. this occurs when the list is moving and the button is pressed. Is there any way to prevent this?

this Code of button click. here arrlist is the arraylist and dailydata() is used to add data to  the array list.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
arrlist.clear();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
dailydata();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

}

Comment: could u show the code you change the data and call notifyDatasetChanged?

Answer (score 0):

You might be changing the content before notifying the adapter. Or you can try disabling the click on button while ListView is scrolling. Share your code so that we could find the exact error.

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged() is called just after the data is changed. There is a lot of code to post.

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` is reading data from `Adapter` while you changing it. Use `synchronized` blocks inside your `Adapter` for read and edit. This will prevent `ListView` to read data before `notifyDatasetChanged()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating custom list view you should be careful when each row will inflate dynamically when moving up and down, please check you getview method or post it here..

Comment: getinflateview? did you main getView? 
i am not overriding getinflateview in my adapter.